# How can I use setAttribute on an input without an ID or class attribute?

Tags: javascript

I have a search input tag that is being added by a jQuery plug-in:

```
<input type="search" />
```

Note that this does not have an ID, CLASS, or NAME. I need the search input tag to look like this:

```
<input type="search" name="myname" />
```

A simple solution is for me to update the jQuery plug-in. However, I do not want to do this as it will cause challenges when I upgrade this plug-in in the future.

This JavaScript works properly and adds the name attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].setAttribute("name", "myname");
});
```

The problem is that the "[0]" in this function relies on the search input being the first input field in the form. I do not think this solution is sustainable.

There are other inputs in the form. This is the only one with the type attribute equal to "search." Is there a way to identify it by this attribute? Or, is there another solution you propose?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does the plugin add a parent element with a unique identifier you can target?

Comment: Hi Jorg, yes, the input is inside of <div class="filter">.

Comment: `$('input[type=search]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector("input[type='search']")
```

Below is an example (*you can inspect the output to see `name` attribute*):

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=search]").setAttribute("name", "myname");
```

```html
<input type="search" value="foo" />
<input type="bar" value="bar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target a selection by anything. So, the selector `input[type="search"]'` will work.

If you want to apply this to *all* input's of type search, this is good enough, and you get all of them in here:

```
$('input[type="search"]')
```

This works without jQuery too:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="search"]')
```

A more targeted approach would be

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.filter input[type="search"]')
```